# How to keep an asynchronous program running?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm working on a program that uses S22 imap to keep an IDLE connection to gmail and receive messages real time.

I am calling the following function from my Main method:

```
static void RunIdle()
{
    using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "user", "pass", AuthMethod.Login, true))
    {

        if (!Client.Supports("IDLE"))
            throw new Exception("This server does not support IMAP IDLE");

        Client.DefaultMailbox = "label";
        Client.NewMessage += new EventHandler<IdleMessageEventArgs>(OnNewMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to gmail");

        while (true)
        {
            //keep the program running until terminated
        }

    }
}
```

Using the infinite while loop works, but it seems there would be a more correct way to do this. In the future if I want to add more IDLE connections, the only way I see my solution working is with a separate thread for each connection.

What is the best way to accomplish what I am doing with the while loop?

Comment: Why is your method declared `async`, you don't use `await` anywhere in it.

Comment: I was trying other possible solutions. Removed for clarity.

Comment: What sort of program is this?  Console app? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: @JamesThorpe it is a console program at the moment, but will eventually be a service.

Comment: If it'll be a service, you won't need anything like this - the service has it's own message pump and won't stop running.  Just create and use your objects as normal, the events will fire, there's no need to keep a thread tied up "waiting".

Comment: @phosplait Is anything active needed to keep the connection alive, or is it just that you should not dispose of the `ImapClient` instance(s)?

Comment: @Alex The library handles keeping the connection alive. I have removed the using statement and added an infinite sleep to main. This will work until I create a service wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Do not dispose of the client and root it in a static variable. That way it just stays running and keeps raising events. There is no need to have a waiting loop at all. Remove the `using` statement.

If this is the last thread in your program you indeed need to keep it alive.

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to accomplish what I am doing with the while loop?

You may want to do the following two things:

1. Provide your `RunIdle` with a `CancelationToken` so that it can be cleanly stopped.
2. In your  busy waiting `while` loop, use `Task.Delay` to "sleep" until you need to "ping" the mailbox again.

   ```
   static async Task RunIdle(CancelationToken cancelToken, TimeSpan pingInterval)
   {
       // ...

       // the new busy waiting ping loop
       while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           // Do your stuff to keep the connection alive.

           // Wait a while, while freeing up the thread.
           if (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
               await Task.Delay(pingInterval, cancelToken);
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you don't need to do anything to keep the connection alive, except from keeping the process from terminating:

   - Read from the console and wait until there is a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or some clean "exit" command.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that avoid thread blocking would be to just use `Task.Delay()` for some random amount of time.

```
static async Task RunIdle(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "user", "pass", AuthMethod.Login, true))
    {

        ...

        var interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `while(true)` you could perhaps use a `CancellationToken` in case the execution needs to be stop at some point. `Task.Delay()` supports this as well.

This are all solutions for a Console application, though. If running as a service, the service host will make sure your program keeps executing after starting, so you can just return.